Is there a way in Javascript to modify the clipboard without the user clicking a button?
I'm working on a small script to streamline the process of re-formatting pasted text, particularly phone numbers. My goal is to paste the text into a textbox and have the formatted result automatically copied to my clipboard to minimize manual clicks.
The function to modify the clipboard only works when a real click event occurs. I've attempted various approaches such as programmatically calling .click(), dispatching a "click" event, utilizing async/await, and promises
JSFiddle Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ByteBender/7bukf5xh/9/
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('paste', event => {
    const contents = event.clipboardData.getData('text')
    if (contents.length >= 9) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const formattedNumber = formatPhoneNumber(contents)
        myInput.value = formattedNumber
        copyToClipboard()
        
      // Also failed to copy
      //myButton.click()
      // Also failed to copy
      //setTimeout( () => myButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')), 500 )
    }
});

function copyToClipboard() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value)
    .then(()=> console.log('success!'))
    .catch(err=>console.error(`fail: ${err}`))
}


// Also failed to copy
/* function tempButton(){
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = 'click me';
  button.onclick = function(){
    copyToClipboard();
        return false;
  };
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  //button.click()
  
} */


would you use a browser that allows websites to do that?

In Chrome/Chromium, I believe this should work unmodified. Firefox requires transient activation.
As a workaround, you could window.addEventListener() for all possible transient-activation-granting events, and use the clipboard API in there.
clipboardFunc = () => { 
  navigator.clipboard.writeText("hello");
  console.log("Copied to clipboard! Removing self.");
  removeClipboardFunc();
}

removeClipboardFunc = () => {
  window.removeEventListener("keydown", clipboardFunc);
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", clipboardFunc);

I think it's probably a good idea to question if it's really a good idea to circumvent the protections and work against the user like this. What if somebody had something important in their clipboard??
